# фокус item listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Здравствуйте! Есть ли какой-нибудь метод, с помощью которого можно узнать на какой item ил ListView был наведен фокус(т.е. нажали на item но не отпустили)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mListView.getSelectedItem()` и следующие за ним в документации два метода вам должны помочь.

[GetSelectedItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem()) - документация